# 8000000E A method was called at an unexpected time from await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(id);

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have some code that calls await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(id); from a DeviceInformation watcher. The BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(id) throws the exception "drivers\wdm\bluetooth\user\winrt\device\bluetoothledevice.cpp(606)\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll!00007FFE61CEE93E: (caller: 00007FFE61CF546A) Exception(2) tid(22cc) 8000000E A method was called at an unexpected time." I am running Windows 10 and have paired 2 devices prior to running my code and it is interesting to note that the exception is thrown for 1 device while the BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(id) succeeds for a different device. I have also implemented an unmanaged C++ version of the code that interacts with both devices just fine. Any ideas on why the "A method was called at an unexpected time" would be appreciated.